# Structural Induction - bit strings

Tags: logic, induction

In this task, we will look at a function that calculates the "cross sum" of
a bit string, that is, which returns the number of occurrences of 1 in a bit string. For example, we have that f(110011) = 4
and f(000) = 0. We choose to define f recursively by saying that f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1, f(s0) = f(s)
and f(s1) = f(s) + 1, for a bit string s. Prove by structural induction that f calculates the cross sum of a bit string, that is say it works as it should.

I think have define the basis step correctly:
Let P stand for the claim.
If P(0) is true:
f(0) = 0 = f(00)

If P(1) is true:
f(1) 0 + 1 = f(0) + 1 = f(01)

But I can't understand what the induction hypothesis.
I tried f(s) = f(s1), but I don't think that works.

If you have some insight, let me know.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've added more info now :)